# Get previously selected item from- Spinner OnItemSelectedListener event

Tags: java, android

Is there a way that I can get the previously selected item from a ItemSelected event on a spinner? My first thought was to respond to the OnItemClickedEvent, but that method is not supported for spinners.

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
                {

                MyItem current = (MyItem) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                //MyItem previous = (MyItem) parent.getPrevious ... how
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent)
                {
                //do nothing
                }
            });
```

I'm aware I can just cache the previous value, but it seems like a common operation that there should be a method for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a variable to track the previous item. It would likely be at member of the Activity.

```
    MyItem previous, current;
    ...

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
            {
                previous = current
                current = (MyItem) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent)
            {
            //do nothing
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(
            new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                int prev = comboValues.getSelectedItemPosition();
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
                                            prev=position;
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {


                }

            }
    );
```

> Note that nothing happens if you select an item you have already selected